# Библиотека JS для редактирования doc

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как реализовать веб приложение на JS, которое будет редактировать doc файл ?

Задача следующая : есть doc файл, в нем есть метки (например name , size , profit и т.д.). По сути у меня есть стандартный договор на оказания услуг, который я делаю по несколько раз в день.
Мной будет создан сайт, на котором есть различные input поля. Когда я их ввожу и нажал кнопку "сгенерировать", должен формироваться doc документ, с уже заполненными полями.
До этого я реализовывал десктопную программу на С# на webform. В папке у меня был doc файл. Я вводил в программе все поля, затем с помощью библиотеки Office.Interop.Word на рабочем столе создавался готовый документ.

Теперь я хочу сделать что-то наподобие web приложения. Пока я не совсем понимаю, может ли JS редактировать и создавать doc документ, который я загружу к примеру на свой хостинг ? и потом выгружать мне его в браузер.
либо такое уже не реализовать без node.js ?
и главный вопрос, какую библиотеку для этого использовать ?

Comment: Клиентский JS в браузере не может взаимодействовать с файловой системой ПК. Можно на клиенте запрашивать данные, отсылать их на сервер, формировать документ и возвращать пользователю. Серверную часть выбирайте по своему желанию

Comment: неужели, @SwaD https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Comment: забыл упомянуть, что мне необязательно именно делать doc файл, подойдет и docx, на край pdf.
Насколько я понял , docx это обычный архив с файлами xml, потому есть способ решить эту задачу

Comment: Удалось ли решить задачу?
интересен способ реализации